# Json4s Extraction of BigDecimal fails

Tags: java, scala, bigdecimal, json4s

i am using json4s in one of my projects. In one particular case i am trying to Extract a resultSet map whose signature is-

```
List[Map[String,Any]]
```

Sometimes the resultSet contains `java.math.BigDecimal` values and in that case the extraction fails with the following message -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not a primitive class java.math.BigDecimal
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at org.json4s.Extraction$.writePrimitive(Extraction.scala:232) ~[json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar:3.2.11]
        at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:126) ~[json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar:3.2.11]
        at org.json4s.Extraction$.addField$1(Extraction.scala:82) ~[json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar:3.2.11]
        at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:132) ~[json4s-core_2.11-3.2.11.jar:3.2.11]
```

Any ideas on why this error. I can see the source code of json4s [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/69075379/) and as per this BigDecimal should be handled.

Comment: you have any sample code?

Comment: i call Extraction.decompose(data) where data is the List of map that i showed above.